# Getting Checked exception is invalid for this method! Invalid error in Mockito Unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

need ur help.

When I am writing a UT, Where my main function is something like this:

```
public String handleRequest(.......){
try {
.....
......
xyz.sendEmail(sesClient, emailSender, emailRecepient, mailSubject, mailBody);
.....
.....
catch (EmailMessagingException de) {
.......
}
}
```

```
public  void sendEmail(@NonNull final AmazonSimpleEmailService sesClient, @NonNull String emailSender,
    @NonNull String emailRecepient, @NonNull String subject, @NonNull String body) throws EmailMessagingException{
    try {
        SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest()
                .withDestination(
    new Destination().withToAddresses(emailRecepient)) .withMessage(new Message()
.withBody(new Body()
.withText(new Content()
.withCharset("UTF-8").withData(body)))
.withSubject(new Content()
.withCharset("UTF-8").withData(subject)))
.withSource(emailSender);
sesClient.sendEmail(request); } catch (Exception ex) { System.out.println("The email was not sent. Error message: "
    ex.getMessage()); throw new EmailMessagingException("Error when sending email via ses", ex); } }
```

My UT looks like this:

```
public void testHandleRequestForEmailMessagingException()throws Exception{ 
when(sesClient.sendEmail(Mockito.any())).thenThrow(EmailMessagingException.class); 
assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, ()->xyz.handleRequest(abc, context)); 
        ...... 
        ..... 
verify(emailUtil).sendEmail(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
 }
```

Now, when running this UT, I get error

Checked exception is invalid for this method! Invalid: EmailMessagingException
I wrote another UT which tests similar other exception from a method call in same main method.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Please can you format your code? It is nearly impossible to read.

Comment: Is there more than one EmailMessagingException class, and you're importing the wrong one?

Comment: Your code is very unclear, and I can't tell for sure which methods belonmg to which classes, but `sesClient.sendEmail(request)` doesn't appear to throw an `EmailMessagingException`. That's thrown from `sendEmail(@NonNull final AmazonSimpleEmailService sesClient...`.

Comment: @AndyTurner I have edited the code.

Comment: @tgdavies I believe it throws exception if you look closely at method signature.

Comment: No, it doesn't throw any checked exceptions: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/AmazonSimpleEmailService.html#sendEmail-com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.model.SendEmailRequest-

Comment: It looks as though `emailUtil` is a mock, so why do you even need a mock of `AmazonSimpleEmailService`?

Comment: Fixed it, seems instead of this  when(sesClient.sendEmail(Mockito.any())).thenThrow(EmailMessagingException.class); 
it should be when(emailUtil.sendEmail(Mockito.any())).thenThrow(EmailMessagingException.class);